# How will dynamically created object be parent of dynamically created another object?

Tags: delphi

- I have two database tables related to master.
- I create panels of master  dynamically (stated in code below) with while loop in the table.
- I name those master objects as b+ autoincrement value of the master table and at each row, I want to create its childs into the object i just created.

But when I try to make child object's parents same as I named master object I get this error :

> [DCC Error] mimik.pas(558): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TWinControl' and 'TControl'

I request your help. I will be appreciated.

```
Procedure bakimguncelle;  // This is the procedure to refresh my main screen
var
  i :integer;
  f:Tcxgroupbox;
  g:tcontrol;
begin
  i:=0;

  freeandnil(form1.ScrollBox1);

  with TScrollbox.Create(Form1) do   
  begin
    parent:=form1.takip;
    name:='Scrollbox1';
    align:=alclient;
  end;

  form1.ScrollBox1.CleanupInstance;

  i:=0;

  data.DataModule1.unite.First;
  while not data.DataModule1.unite.eof do
  begin
    with Tcxgroupbox.Create(Form1) do     //  master objects created in scrollbox
    begin
      parent:=form1.ScrollBox1;              
      Name:='b'+data.DataModule1.uniteUniteId.AsString;
      width:=parent.Width;
      align:=altop;
      height:=122;
      g.Name:=name;    
      caption:=data.DataModule1.uniteAdi.Value;
      style.LookAndFeel.NativeStyle:=false;
      style.LookAndFeel.SkinName:='Silver';
      visible:=true;
    end;

    data.DataModule1.makina.First;
    while not data.DataModule1.makina.eof do
    begin
      with TScrollbox.Create(Form1) do   //child objects are tried to be created in master
      begin
        parent:='b'+data.DataModule1.uniteUniteId.AsString;
        Align:=altop;
        name:='df'+inttostr(random(34247));  // just trial
        randomize;
      end;
      data.DataModule1.makina.Next;
    end;

    data.DataModule1.unite.Next;
    i:=i+1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please take some time to fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: This needs to be rewritten from scratch (you e.g. release the object referenced by the `Form1.ScrollBox1` and use it as parent; creating a component with the name of that released object won't assign it to that field again). Naming of components created at runtime has no meaning (in well designed code).

Comment: what do you mean , i did not understand

Comment: What you're trying to do seems strange.  Even if your attempt to create a scrollbox succeeded, you would end up with as many of them as there are rows  in your makina dataset, all aligned alClient.  It might help if you edited your code to explain what you are trying to do.  Btw, have you looked at TDBCtrilGrid - it does similar to what you might be trying to?

Comment: I guess `takip` is `TControl` rather than `TWinControl`. But yes, all this code has to go and you need to learn the basics before you proceed.

Comment: ok thanks lemme start again with tdbctrlgrid  thanks

Comment: yepp tdbctrlgrid is the one. THANKS I AM APPReciated.

Comment: but here is the news ,  for master table its ok. 

but i want to put another tdbctrlgrid in tdbctrlgrid row,
is this possible ?

Comment: I have never tried nesting one DBCtrlGrid inside another one myself, but if I were you, I'd just try it.

Comment: @TLama: "creating a component with the name of that released object won't assign it to that field again" - actually it does. The `TComponent.Name` setter calls `TComponent.SetReference()`, which sets the corresponding named field. This is how DFM streamed components get assigned to fields at runtime, and the `Name` setter has no concept of whether it is being called by a DFM or not.

Comment: @Remy, that surprises me a bit. So you can overwrite an existing component reference if you create a component instance with the same name (or it throws an exception like IDE does) ? [have no Delphi by hand]

Comment: @TLama: in short, yes. When a component object is destroyed, it calls `SetName('')` and thus `SetReference(False)`, which sets the corresponding field to nil. A new component object can then set its `Name` to the old value, thus calling `SetReference(True)` to set its `Self` pointer to the field. Note that this only works for `published` fields, due to the use of old-style `TypInfo` RTTI in `TObject.FieldAddress()` to find the field.  And a `TComponent` owner does not allow multiple owned components to have the same `Name` value, otherwise an "already exists" exception is raised.